# Hybrid environments, 404 with on-premise mailboxes, 200 for Exchange online

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I've written an application which is able to talk to Exchange Online accounts, I'm currently trying to test to see the steps required to get it to work with on-premise accounts running in Hybrid.

I have:

- Windows Server 2012 R2
- Exchange 2016 CU8 (with `/PrepareAD` run)
- Internet accessible paths to `/api/v2.0` and `/autodiscover/autodiscover.json`
- Run the HCW
- AD Connect is running
- Active Directory is synced to Azure Active Directory
- Permissions look good on the application that I have registered (read calendar events / read-write calendar events)

Unfortunately, I'm getting a `404` when trying to access calendar events:

```
curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6IkFRQUJBQUFBQUFCSGg0a21TX2FLVDVYcmp6eFJBdEh6RE1mbEZNYTYwaktGRHRhUXp0ZGVkM2V6Z0ZfUzlLMjdDRmQxSHlfZGdRcnR6WlJBczRDV095R3E1Vl9OZW9MSFNKTGpzblNCSDNCQU9oQnBzU18wVmlBQSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2IiwieDV0IjoiU1NRZGhJMWNLdmhRRURTSnhFMmdHWXM0MFEwIiwia2lkIjoiU1NRZGhJMWNLdmhRRURTSnhFMmdHWXM0MFEwIn0.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.AWt_ANsH8sk15WeH1AgD6SD0Ki8VILMvzkbSMju_YFGKc5cVkrGp7Skzt64uDM8rI6Py5Y-1c3srXwON2oSihkRskfz5vG4nIlbFnuYd3Ij2Vz1ktpNnCeMAnAK2T8ifk2visRSvchRbuBNZZyamwRjActdDF9BS8NygUgmmygK4mPjOIab17PJPz5PisvRbCA2jBLWLvbu9RYrLH-xGuoLd2PLTbsn2WSVi3er4XztZCcK7XfVWe-0wjrV6qBufd5z0hH_KpQLdzPtLOzSUGUAcXGa0mBPceTWULQvQ-LPcAJO57F0ir5k22fWzlkOfUxQb9eGWREUm1cAPWk3CPw" "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/oq@healthcentrified.co.uk/calendar/events"
*   Trying 137.116.241.64...
* Connected to graph.microsoft.com (137.116.241.64) port 443 (#0)
* found 148 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 592 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
*        server certificate verification OK
*        server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*        common name: graph.microsoft.com (matched)
*        server certificate expiration date OK
*        server certificate activation date OK
*        certificate public key: RSA
*        certificate version: #3
*        subject: C=US,ST=WA,L=Redmond,O=Microsoft Corporation,OU=Microsoft Corporation,CN=graph.microsoft.com
*        start date: Wed, 03 Jan 2018 17:32:18 GMT
*        expire date: Fri, 03 Jan 2020 17:32:18 GMT
*        issuer: C=US,ST=Washington,L=Redmond,O=Microsoft Corporation,OU=Microsoft IT,CN=Microsoft IT TLS CA 4
*        compression: NULL
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
> GET /v1.0/users/oq@healthcentrified.co.uk/calendar/events HTTP/1.1
> Host: graph.microsoft.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6IkFRQUJBQUFBQUFCSGg0a21TX2FLVDVYcmp6eFJBdEh6RE1mbEZNYTYwaktGRHRhUXp0ZGVkM2V6Z0ZfUzlLMjdDRmQxSHlfZGdRcnR6WlJBczRDV095R3E1Vl9OZW9MSFNKTGpzblNCSDNCQU9oQnBzU18wVmlBQSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2IiwieDV0IjoiU1NRZGhJMWNLdmhRRURTSnhFMmdHWXM0MFEwIiwia2lkIjoiU1NRZGhJMWNLdmhRRURTSnhFMmdHWXM0MFEwIn0.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.AWt_ANsH8sk15WeH1AgD6SD0Ki8VILMvzkbSMju_YFGKc5cVkrGp7Skzt64uDM8rI6Py5Y-1c3srXwON2oSihkRskfz5vG4nIlbFnuYd3Ij2Vz1ktpNnCeMAnAK2T8ifk2visRSvchRbuBNZZyamwRjActdDF9BS8NygUgmmygK4mPjOIab17PJPz5PisvRbCA2jBLWLvbu9RYrLH-xGuoLd2PLTbsn2WSVi3er4XztZCcK7XfVWe-0wjrV6qBufd5z0hH_KpQLdzPtLOzSUGUAcXGa0mBPceTWULQvQ-LPcAJO57F0ir5k22fWzlkOfUxQb9eGWREUm1cAPWk3CPw
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Cache-Control: private
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/plain
< request-id: f499015e-325b-45e8-9716-0a8a7160b82d
< client-request-id: f499015e-325b-45e8-9716-0a8a7160b82d
< x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"North Europe","Slice":"SliceA","Ring":"3","ScaleUnit":"003","Host":"AGSFE_IN_0","ADSiteName":"DUB"}}
< Duration: 1764.3754
< Date: Sun, 18 Feb 2018 19:18:28 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host graph.microsoft.com left intact
```

If I do a similar request on a mailbox that has been migrated to Exchange Online, this works (I get an `HTTP 200` and a list of events back in JSON)

Office 365 support is unsure of what to do here (it is probably beyond their scope).

The [documentation says that it is in preview](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/hybrid_rest_support), but, should still work

> Microsoft Graph has always provided access to customer mailboxes in the cloud on Exchange Online as part of Office 365. Exchange 2016 Cumulative Update 3 (CU3), released in September 2016 for Exchange on-premises servers, adds support for REST API integration with Office 365. If your app uses v1.0 of the Mail, Calendar, or Contacts API, you will now also find a seamless authentication and application experience in hybrid deployments, regardless of whether the mailbox is on-premises or in the cloud, provided that the deployment meets specific requirements.
>
> Behind the scenes, when Microsoft Graph identifies that a REST API
>   call is attempting to access an on-premises mailbox in a hybrid
>   deployment, it proxies the REST request to an on-premises REST
>   endpoint which then processes the request. This discovery makes
>   accessing the REST API possible.

I will state that I have very limited Windows experience and this is my first foray into using Windows servers for anything, however, the lack of documentation on this scenario, since this is probably something that a lot of large corporate organizations would want to do.

Is there anything obviously wrong?

*Update*

Rasmus asked if I had any requests going to my web server and whilst I can see a lot of traffic on `/rpc` I get nothing hitting `autodiscover.json` and the only requests to `/API` are

```
2018-02-25 18:58:24 ::1 
GET /api/v1.0/users/HealthMailboxda9cb9ff7af047cf9878a9b7be391e14@healthcentrified.co.uk/Messages 
$top=1
&request_id=4f17c7a2-f753-46f7-853d-36f7a5281932 444 
- ::1 Odata_AM_Probe/Local - 401 0 0 0
```

And others to this mailbox from this user-agent

Comment: Are you able to see the requests coming in to the on-premises Exchange 2016 CU3? (e.g. in the IIS logs)

Comment: No, the only requests to anything matching /API are to an Exchange system mailbox - I've put a logline into the question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked your token on https://jwt.ms and found out it's an Application token from the Client Credentials Flow. This isn't supported out of the box but today I've found out that you can enable these tokens on your on-premise exchange environment.

See my answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56131954/639153

Original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56108226/639153)

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the explanation - I had unfortunately given up on Hybrid and instead mandated the use of 365 only.

It's a little lame that while the Graph API touts that Hybrid environments work that it is documented so poorly.

I do appreciate the answer and will look forward to using this the next time I have to do any Graph API work with Windows kit