# Azure client credentials grant oath not working in hybrid setup for Graph Mail API access

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

In hybrid setup if client credentials grant type is used to get token and if that token is used to get on-prem user messages (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('onpremuser@onpremdomain.com')/messages/) using graph api it fails by providing UnknownError.

When debugged on IIS logs error shown was "This token profile 'V1S2SAppOnly' is not applicable for the current protocol." error_category="invalid_token".

However if authorization code grant or resource owner password credential (ROPC) grant if used to obtain token , we were able to get messages of on prem user using graph API.
Have attached screenshot of token for both. How to make client credentials grant work for on-prem user messages access using graph API (in hybrid setup) ?

[image: Client credentials oath flow]

[image: ROPC oath flow]

## Update

Update i went and edited web.config of rest in Exchange server to have V1S2SAppOnly in profiles. After that previous error is gone and new error is seen.

Bearer+client_id="00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000",+trusted_issuers="00000001-0000-0000-c000-000000000000@ea6064aa-d6fc-48d3-abb8-1728e1f39e0b",+token_types="app_asserted_user_v1+service_asserted_app_v1",+error="invalid_token" 2000008;reason="**The+token+should+have+valid+permissions+or+linked+account+associated+with+partner+application+'00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000**'.";error_category="invalid_grant"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exchange 2016 on-premise mailbox access using Graph API (Hybrid Setup)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54932152/exchange-2016-on-premise-mailbox-access-using-graph-api-hybrid-setup)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the `aud` claim, i.e. the audience for token.

For the first token that you have shared

- `aud` value is `00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000`. This is the resource Id for Azure AD Graph API and not Microsoft Graph API. For Microsoft Graph API, you should be using `https://graph.microsoft.com` or Id `00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000`
- this token is probably the one where you used client credentials grant, as there isn't any user claim

For the second token that you have shared

- `aud` value is `https://graph.microsoft.com` which is correct
- this token is acquired in context of a user name `anoop` so I guess this is the one which is working for you.

Comment: Even with graph as aud fails with same error.{
  "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com/",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxx/",
  "iat": 1552573576,
  "nbf": 1552573576,
  "exp": 1552577476,
  "aio": "42JgYEjYOn3DtYdvWBUE7ks/nDt3LQA=",
  ...
}

Comment: Also i started doubting if IIS is supporting claims without user as valid token all together . Because the error msg displayed is "This token profile 'V1S2SAppOnly' is not applicable for the current protocol."   On other hand for token with user claims i can see "USER_SET AuthType="Bearer", UserName="S-1-5-21-1392771109-4043059535-3934338706-1147", SupportsIsInRole="true"" in IIS trace logging but fails at same point for client credentials token (which has no user claims)

Comment: @KarthikHebbar ok there may be more issues at play.. at least the `aud` needs to be correct first.. further.. Error message is such that token version could be an issue, but I see both your tokens are v1 so not fully making sense yet.. Can you please tell how you registered your application? regular `Azure AD portal`, `App Registrations preview experience` or `apps.dev.microsoft.com` .. also how are you acquiring the token.. using a library or direct REST API calls.. share some code details if possible

Comment: I did app registration in Azure portal using App registration. I am doing direct REST api calls in postman currently (switched from code directly).  Token URL  - https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT ID>/oauth2/token, params - resource (https://graph.microsoft.com/) , client_id , client secret and grant_type as client_credentials.   And calling api https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('unprem user')/messages/ with obtained token.  Important observation is everything works perfectly for cloud users. Problem is with on prem users only.

Comment: REST api calls done from postman with mentioned parameters in previous comment.

Comment: @KarthikHebbar ok got it.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is:

`Application with Client credentials` => `Graph API` => `Local Exchange`.

This scenario isn't supported out-of-the-box, but you can however tell your local exchange server to accept those tokens. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56131954/639153

In a nutshell, you need to change the authentication config of your front-end exchange servers to accept client credentials from the graph api. By default only delegated credentials are supported, and these settings are not documented on the exchange side.

**Warning**, we tested these settings, and it's working but **not supported by Microsoft**

This is the blog where I've found the answer to your question. https://blog.thenetw.org/2019/05/13/using-client_credentials-with-microsoft-graph-in-hybrid-exchange-setup/