# Microsoft Graph API - Exchange Server Hybrid Deployment - Resource could not be discovered

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server

We have deployed Exchange server hybrid mode with Office 365.

However, we cannot use MS Graph API to get messages in mailboxes on Premise Exchange.

Below is the error we have got:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ResourceNotFound",
        "message": "Resource could not be discovered.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "75aa59fb-06a3-4788-b2ac-d5cec9a6dbeb",
            "date": "2019-11-20T19:21:31"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of flow are you using? If using the client credentials flow it might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48872571/hybrid-environments-404-with-on-premise-mailboxes-200-for-exchange-online/56132446#56132446 see the answer in this post.

Comment: Hello Stephan, "client credentials grant flow" is being used (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service). I will check out that post, Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hybrid environments, 404 with on-premise mailboxes, 200 for Exchange online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48872571/hybrid-environments-404-with-on-premise-mailboxes-200-for-exchange-online)